# mod_security flush persistence

Tags: mod-security

I run a website with a resource & time consuming URL, say ~20 seconds per request. In the last few days this URL is being targeted by some kind of DoS attack, and I'm trying to use mod_security so none can abuse this URL. It makes no sense a real (ie human) user hits this URL more than once every 5 seconds, so I ended up with this:

```
<LocationMatch "/mySlowUrl/">
        SecRuleEngine on
        SecAction phase:2,id:10001,initcol:IP=%{REMOTE_ADDR},pass,nolog
        SecRule IP:soslow "@eq 1" phase:2,id:10002,deny,status:503,nolog,setenv:SOSLOW
        SecAction phase:2,id:10003,setvar:IP.soslow=1,expirevar:IP.soslow=5,pass,nolog
        Header always set Retry-After "5" env=SOSLOW
</LocationMatch>
```

It "works", but as long as persistent storage is only saved at the end of request processing, IP:soslow is only set after the whole 20 seconds first request, so the attacker still has 20 seconds to overload the server.

Is there any way to flush persistent variables so they are written as soon as rule is processed (in phase 2)? Any other idea to stop this attacks?